# Sorting of array that has items containing both numeric and characters using LINQ's OrderBy is not working properly

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to short the ID which contains both numbers and characters as below

```
string[] dataIDs = new string[] { "001", "002", "010", "011", "EMP001", "EMP010", "EMP002", "EMP011" };

foreach (var item in dataIDs.OrderBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

```
'001', '010', '011', '002', 'EMP001', 'EMP010', 'EMP011', 'EMP002'
```

But I am expecting as:

```
'001', '002', '010', '011', 'EMP001', 'EMP002', 'EMP010', 'EMP011'
```

Comment: I tried to run your code, and I'm getting your expected output. Can you check it again?

Comment: No, its not working

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KQZGtf).

Comment: I tired to run the code i'm also getting expected output

Comment: If you are not getting the expected output, that doesn't necessarily mean that _"OrderBy is not working properly"_.

Comment: I'd rephrase that to "Not working as expected". It doesn't seem to be an issue with `OrderBy` since it's working fine for other people. Try checking the `Culture` as Kiran suggested in [a comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56928554/9833095).

Comment: Anyone can reproduce this issue ??

Answer (score 4):

you can use this :)

```cs
string[] dataIDs = new string[] { "001", "002", "010", "011", "EMP001", "EMP010", "EMP002", "EMP011" };

foreach (var item in dataIDs.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Can you advise why this works (as an edit; for OP's understanding)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.

I tried with the given solution, but its returns the same as exist before.

Is there any other solution, please let me know

Comment: but its work for me! This is the output  '001', '002', '010', '011', 'EMP001', 'EMP002', 'EMP010', 'EMP011'

Comment: Please check the current thread culture information. This information effects how sorting works. Please look into this Microsoft document for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinal?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] dataIDs = new string[] { "001", "002", "010", "011", "EMP001", "EMP010", "EMP002", "EMP011" };

var result = dataIDs.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.Ordinal);

foreach (var Item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Item);
}
```